# Delete Request with formData not passing trough WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I am trying to do a Delete Request with formData as a parameter. For some reason the parameter is not being passed to the server side. When I do the call directly to the server the formData is passed, but through WSO2 AM it **does not**.

Can anyone help please. Is there a setting we need to activate or something.

Comment: what is the response you got from api manager when you do so?

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your scenario in latest API Manager pack. Anyway when we send a delete request to the server, Resource which is to be deleted is identified by the request URI not by entities in request. You can find more information on [spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

> The DELETE method requests that the origin server delete the resource
>   identified by the Request-URI.

According to the debug session I had in synapse code, code is written in a way that DELETE request has not any entity in it. So any form data you sent in request will be ignored from request. It is done by design.